# Html2Canvas sometime callback not firing final solution

Tags: html2canvas

I faced a problem when I used the [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) plugin, sometimes callback function was not executed,

look at the example below:

```
html2canvas(element.get(0), {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            allowTaint: true,
            scale: 3,
        }).then(canvas => {
            
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            alert('worked!');

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem and solved it, the problem in the plugin process, while first thing was to create a canvas and then reinitialize events for this element (iframe by the plugin) and resolve this by promise,  but if the elements were already loaded(readyState) is complete the events will be ignored,

so the solution below:

replace this function below:

```
var iframeLoader = function (iframe) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var cloneWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
            if (!cloneWindow) {
                return reject("No window assigned for iframe");
            }
            var documentClone = cloneWindow.document;
            cloneWindow.onload = iframe.onload = function () {
                cloneWindow.onload = iframe.onload = null;
                var interval = setInterval(function () {
                    if (documentClone.body.childNodes.length > 0 && documentClone.readyState === 'complete') {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        resolve(iframe);
                    }
                }, 50);
            };
        });
    };
```

**with this below:**

```
 var iframeLoader = function (iframe) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var cloneWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
        if (!cloneWindow) {
            return reject("No window assigned for iframe");
        }

        var isEventFired = false;
        var documentClone = cloneWindow.document;
        cloneWindow.onload = iframe.onload = documentClone.onreadystatechange = function () {
            isEventFired = true;
            cloneWindow.onload = iframe.onload = documentClone.onreadystatechange = null;
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (documentClone.body.childNodes.length > 0 && documentClone.readyState === 'complete') {
                    console.log(`S3 =>  documentClone.readyState is: ${documentClone.readyState}, isEventFired: ${isEventFired}`);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve(iframe);
                }
            }, 100);
        };
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!isEventFired) {
                var retry = 10, retryCount = 0;
                // every 1sec check DOM cloned state is complete loaded or not.
                var iframeEventExecution = setInterval(function () {
                    console.log(`S2 =>  documentClone.readyState is: ${documentClone.readyState}, isEventFired: ${isEventFired}, retryCount: ${retryCount}`);
                    if ((!isEventFired && documentClone.readyState === 'complete') || retryCount >= retry) {
                        clearInterval(iframeEventExecution);
                        resolve(iframe);
                    }
                    else {
                        retryCount++;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }, 250);

    });
};
```